# First row always selected in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having an issue keeping the first row of my JTable selected. I have tried the following:

1.

```
customersTable.requestFocus();
customersTable.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
```

2.

```
customersTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
customersTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0, 0);
customersTable.setColumnSelectionInterval(0, 0);
customersTable.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Both of these methods work, but only when I add a new customer to the table and `populateCustomerTable()` is called, which is where I have placed this bit of code. `populateCustomerTable()` is called during the method that creates the JTable, so I am not sure why it isn't working. I have tried placing both pieces of code directly in the method that creates the JTable, but both do not work.

I am expecting the first row of the table to be selected as soon as the program starts, but it only actually does what I want it to after I have entered a customer into the table.

Here is the code to set up my JTable:

```
private JPanel customersTable() {
        JPanel panelCustomersTable = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        customersTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {
                "First Name", "Last Name", "House Number", "Address",
                "City", "Postcode", "Phone Number"
        }, 0);

        customersTable = new JTable(customersTableModel ) {


            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return false;
            }

            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int row, int col) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, row, col);

                if (row % 2 == 0) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    c.setBackground(new Color(234, 234, 234));
                }

                if (isRowSelected(row)) {
                    c.setBackground(new Color(24, 134, 254));
                }

                return c;
            }
        };

        customersTable.setFont(new Font("", 0, 14));
        customersTable.setRowHeight(customersTable.getRowHeight() + 10);
        customersTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        customersTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);


        customersTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    //editCustomer(frame?)
                }

                try {
                    int row = customersTable.getSelectedRow();
                    String houseNumber = customersTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString();
                    String address = customersTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3).toString();
                    String city = customersTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString();
                    //populateMap(houseNumber, address, city);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    /*
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please select an item to delete.",
                                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                     */
                }
            }
        });



        populateCustomersTable();



        customersTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);


        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(customersTable,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);


        panelCustomersTable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        panelCustomersTable.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelCustomersTable.add(customersTableButtons(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panelCustomersTable.add(customersTableSearch(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        return panelCustomersTable;
    }
```

This is my populateCustomersTable method:

```
private static void populateCustomersTable() {
        int rows = customersTableModel.getRowCount();
        for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
            customersTableModel.removeRow(i);
        }

        Database.selectCustomers();

        for (int i = 0; i < Database.getCustomersArray().size(); i++) {

            String firstName = Database.getCustomersArray().get(i).getFirstName();
            String lastName = Database.getCustomersArray().get(i).getLastName(); 
            String houseNumber = Database.getCustomersArray().get(i).getHouseNumber();
            String address = Database.getCustomersArray().get(i).getAddress();
            String city = Database.getCustomersArray().get(i).getCity();
            String postcode = Database.getCustomersArray().get(i).getPostcode();
            String phoneNumber = Database.getCustomersArray().get(i).getPhoneNumber();


            Object[] data = {firstName, lastName, houseNumber, address, city,
                    postcode, phoneNumber
            };


            customersTableModel.addRow(data);
            customersTable.requestFocus();
            customersTable.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You question is about row selection, so the data in the table is irrelevant as is the custom rendering. So post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. All you need is to use the DefaultTableModel to set the row/colums of the table. Then you do your row selection. Get this working first and then apply the knowledge to your real application.

Comment: Also, 1) you can only request focus on a table displayed on a visible window. 2) You should be using `requestFocusInWindow()`, not requestFocust(). 3) to remove rows from a `DefaultTableModel` you can just use the `setRowCount(0)` method;

Comment: Please explain what you want. Do you want to keep first line selected when nothing else in the table is selected or you want to keep the first line selected always?

Comment: I'd like the first row to be selected at all times, thanks.

Comment: `I am expecting the first row of the table to be selected as soon as the program starts, but it only actually does what I want it to after I have entered a customer into the table.` - which makes sense. You can't select a row unless you have data in the TableModel. `I'd like the first row to be selected at all times` - and what if the user clicks on a row?